# Keystone and Cloudinary

Tags: image, cloudinary, keystone

I am working with keystone and am trying to upload images to the website generated by running

```
yo keystone
```

I have set up a cloudinary account and updated the keystone.js file by adding

```
keystone.set('cloudinary config', { cloud_name: 'my-cloud', api_key: 'abc', api_secret: '123' });
```

And have updated the .env so that

```
    CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://api_key:api_secret@cloudname
```

But when I try to upload images i get the error

```
Hero Image upload failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.cloudinary.com
```

Did I update the right files? Is there something else I need to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently keystone could not figure out my network's proxy settings so connecting to a different network fixed this